# Is the JavaScript operator === provably transitive?

Tags: javascript, equals, transitivity

JavaScript's quirky weakly-typed `==` operator can easily be shown to be non-transitive as follows:

```
var a = "16";
var b = 16;
var c = "0x10";
alert(a == b && b == c && a != c); // alerts true
```

I wonder if there are any similar tricks one can play with roundoff error, `Infinity`, or `NaN` that could should show `===` to be non-transitive, or if it can be proved to indeed be transitive.

Comment: Are you asking about JavaScript as defined by any particular ECMAScript version, or JavaScript as implemented in any particular browser?

Comment: @Ray `==` isn't transitive because of type coercion. `===` doesn't coerce...

Comment: @zzzzBov I was thinking of ECMAScript 5 but any version of JavaScript will do.

Comment: @Šime Vidas I know `===` does not coerce but I'm not sure that that constitutes a proof.  It very well might....

Comment: @Ray I don't have the time right now to write an elaborate answer, but I've gone through all the cases of the "Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm", and I'm certain that `===` is transitive.

Comment: @Ray this a great one!i just noticed as well that a == c if c = 0x10 and not c = '0x10'. this is quite interesting!

Comment: Cheating: http://jsfiddle.net/JFVcG/1/.

Comment: useful in https://alf.nu/ReturnTrue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `===` operator in Javascript seems to be as transitive as it can get.

`NaN` is reliably different from `NaN`:

```
>>> 0/0 === 0/0
false
>>> 0/0 !== 0/0
true
```

`Infinity` is reliably equal to `Infinity`:

```
>>> 1/0 === 1/0
true
>>> 1/0 !== 1/0
false
```

Objects (hashes) are always different:

```
>>> var a = {}, b = {};
>>> a === b
false
>>> a !== b
true
```

And since the `===` operator does not perform any type coercion, no value conversion can occur, so the equality / inequality semantics of primitive types will remain consistent (i.e. won't contradict one another), interpreter bugs notwithstanding.

Comment: +1 Ah, okay, this can be extended to a more formal full proof by cases on the 6 types of JavaScript: undefined, null, number, boolean, string, and object.  Every value of every type is `===` ONLY to itself (with the exception of NaN which does not "hurt") with no overlaps even with object.

Comment: @Ray, to be fair, the `null` type is still [a work in progress](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:typeof_null) to this day (e.g. `typeof null` returns `object` in my Firefox 6). The sixth type is actually `function`, which is distinct from `object` because it has to implement `call()`.

Comment: @RayToal Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622671/is-the-javascript-operator-provably-transitive/7622921#7622921)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks. I am aware of the workings of `typeof` and the fact that `typeof null` is `"object"` and that the operator returns `"function"` but the workings of this operator is orthogonal to the fact that ECMAScript 5 has six types, regardless of what this operator says.  See Chapter 8 of the [ECMAScript 5 Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf); it is perfectly clear about the six ECMAScript language types.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the spec (http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.6) you will see that no type coercion is being made. Also, everything else is pretty straightforward, so maybe only implementation bugs will make it non-transitive.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the spec.  A positive proof will have to be made by cases on this definition.  I'll try working it out over the next day or so and will accept if it pans out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have variable a,b, and c you can't be 100% certain as shown [here](http://jsbin.com/ayemiy/).  If someone is doing something as hackish as above in production, well then you probably have bigger problems ;)

```
var a = 1;
var b = 1;
Object.defineProperty(window,"c",{get:function(){return b++;}});

alert(a === b && b === c && a !== c); // alerts true
```

Comment: Nice one, found that as well but it's rather cheating :) After all, it's not the `===` that's failing, but rather the fact that the variables are changing. I guess it's implied that `a`, `b` and `c` stay to the same value in the definition of transitivity.

Comment: @pimvdb In the context of what the coder sees `a`,`b`, and `c` are not changing, and therefore it is not transitive `a === b && b === c && a !== c` but hey I guess that is stretching it :D

Comment: @Lime yes very clever, but I would say yes it's a stretch.  I was asking about transitivity in terms of _values_, not _variables_.  The difference matters, but it's a very cool illustration nevertheless!